# How to set hooks execution order with different tags

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, hook

I have a cucumber scenario with different tags
@all @crm @ui @agreementLogic @agreementLogicLazadaActive

And also I have two hooks with differenet values

```
@After(value = "@ui", order = 1)
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            AllureReporter.addScreenShot();
        }
        Browser.stop();
    }
```

and

```
@After(value = "@all",order = 2)
public void afterAll() {
   removeScenarioEnvironment();
    AllureReporter.attachScenarioLogFromLogFile();
}
```

I need that hook for tag @ui been executed before hook for tag @all, as you can see I set them order, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Before(order = int)` : This runs in **increment** order, means value `0` would run first and `1` would be after `0`.

`@After(order = int)` : This runs in **decrement** order, means value `1` would run first and `0` would be after `1`.

**Yours**:

```
@After(value = "@ui", order = 1)
@After(value = "@all",order = 2)
```

**Updated**:

```
@After(value = "@ui", order = 2)
@After(value = "@all",order = 1)
```

Comment: Is that helpful? If yes, can you please accept it.

Comment: sure
thank you!